# For date in column, take a row value and subtract value on another column?

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-formula

For a date in a given column, say Jan-01-2015 with a row value B1, how do I subtract that value in another column for all values that share the date? This assumes that Jan-01-2015 will appear multiple times, thus for a Column C a subtraction would need to be performed on all values of C that share the date Jan-01-2015.

For  two datasets, where the resulting output is in column C:

```
   Date  B         
 1  A   .25          
 2  B   .50          
 3  C   .75
```

For result in Column C, subtract matching dates from Column B in prior dataset:

```
   Date  B     C      
 1  A    4    3.75      
 2  A    5    4.75      
 3  A    6    5.75      
 4  A    7    6.75      
 5  B    1    0.50      
 6  B    1    0.50      
 7  B    2    1.50      
 8  B    3    2.50      
 9  C   -1   -1.75      
10  C   -2   -2.75      
11  C   -3   -3.75      
12  C   -4   -4.75
```

Comment: What operation? You question is not clear.

Comment: Subtraction. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Please show some test data and expected output in tabular form.  Verbal descriptions are hard to follow.

Comment: Why is Date C adding the value. `-1-.75= -1.75`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=B2-VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Date subtraction is done using the function `DateDiff()`

Answer (score 1):

Use vlookup function.
Table 2 coumn C
=b1  - vlookup  (a1,table1.range,3)